# .net 6 web app with auth0 on kubenetes cluster, with nginx ingress as reverse proxy

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, kubernetes

I am trying to deploy a .net 6 web app to AKS with Nginx ingress with auth0.

I can get to the login page, but when I login using auth0, I get the below error.
I am using https for the public ip and from nginx to cluster ip it is set to http.

This is a classic .net core production setup for AKS (https ingress and http inside cluster) and I have scoured the internet for days and have not found any leads.
Would appreciate if anyone could help.

Error from .net 6 web app:

←[40m←[1m←[33mwarn←[39m←[22m←[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler[15]
'.AspNetCore.Correlation.ZWDqdfY7DLPVXkNm-GYikcUJ0TqCOG5vx-OfsI_rMMs' cookie not found.
←[40m←[32minfo←[39m←[22m←[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler[4]
Error from RemoteAuthentication: Correlation failed..
←[41m←[30mfail←[39m←[22m←[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
Connection id "0HMSJQQT6CGVH", Request id "0HMSJQQT6CGVH:00000008": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
System.Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.
---> System.Exception: Correlation failed.
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler`1.HandleRequestAsync()          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)

Deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: webtestapp
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: webtestapp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: webtestapp
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: webtestapp
        image: <aks repository>/<app>:<tag>
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: webtestapp-svc
spec:
  #type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: webtestapp
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80


Ingress.yaml

apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: webtestapp-ingress
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: webtestapp-svc
            port:
              number: 80


Ingress version:

NGINX Ingress controller
  Release:       v1.8.1
  Build:         dc88dce9ea5e700f3301d16f971fa17c6cfe757d
  Repository:    https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx
  nginx version: nginx/1.21.6
```

Created a sample .net 6 web app with auth0 (http). Containerize it with docker and deployed to AKS using the above yaml file. Installed nginx on AKS and created a new ingress.

Was expecting to get this working, as it was working on my local machine from the container.